# Will a block run if it is passed nil as a parameter in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, block

I have the following block in a ruby script:

```
for line in allLines
    line.match(/aPattern/) { |matchData|
        # Do something with matchData
    }
end
```

If `/aPattern/` does not match anything in line, will the block still run? And if not, is there a way I can force it to run?

Comment: From the doc (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-match), it seems the block won't be called if there's no match : "If a block is given, invoke the block with MatchData if match succeed, so that you can write". May I also ask why you want to run it if there's no match ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, the match block will not be run if the match does not suceed. However, `for` is generally not used in Ruby anyways, `each` is more idiomatic, like:

```
allLines.each do |line|
  if line =~ /aPattern/
    do_thing_with_last_match($~) ## $~ is last match
  else
    do_non_match_thing_with_line
  end
end
```

Note, `=~` is a regex match operator.